# MSBuild.exe doesn't exist on Jenkins slave VM

Tags: msbuild, jenkins

I'm having trouble setting up a slave device in Jenkins to build my .net projects. The error I keep getting is FATAL: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe doesn't exist. MSBuild DOES exist on the VM slave in the path above.

I am using the Jenkins MSBuild plug-in, version 1.15 (also didn't work using 1.13). I have set the "path to msbuild" as "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" with no default parameters and install automatically unticked. If I run the same project configuration on the master node, it builds fine.

I have also tried setting the Node Properties - Tool Locations for the slave node but this has no effect either.

Does anyone know how to get Jenkins to see MSBuild on a slave node?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: I ran into this problem because I'd copied the path to msbuild.exe by shift-right-clicking and choosing "Copy as path" from Windows Explorer--I forgot to remove the surrounding quotes when I pasted the path into Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Make sure you do not have quotes in the path in your config. When you "copy as path" using the left-shift right-click method in widows it adds quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to insert whitespace into the beginning of the MSBuild executable path, which apparently made the check-if-exists logic performed by Jenkins to fail.  You would think the MSBuild plugin would trim the input prior to committing the configuration... just remove it and you are fine!